# Include function in php

Tags: php, html

I have a navigation bar page that I can use for all the pages in my website. However, I built a new login page but it is having errors when I connect to the navigation bar page. 
The structure of all my files: 
[image]

I want to apply the navigation bar to my login.php under the uploadTesting2 file. The code for navigation bar I have put in my login.php is :

```
<?php include '../navHeader.php'; ?>
```

The code in the navHearder.php is:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <?php
                    include './data.php';
                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($collectionArr); $i++) {
                        echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a href=\'collectionPage.php?cat=' . $collectionArr[$i]['catCode'] . '\'>';
                        echo $collectionArr[$i]['catName'];
                        echo '</a>';
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="ordering.php">Ordering</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="uploadTesting2/login.php">Admin</a></li>

        </ul>                                 
    </div>
```

However, the code is not working. When I click the index.php, it will show error. the url is wrong and the url is showing: http://localhost:7777/ca2/CA2script/uploadTesting2/index.php

Should I apply one more navgation php in my uploadTesting2 or I can make changes in the navHeader.php?

Answer (score 0):

For best practice define your main(base) url as constant then use it any where.
Suppose your base url is  "http://localhost:7777/ca2/CA2script/"

You can do it like following:

```
define('BASE_URL',"http://localhost:7777/ca2/CA2script/");
```

then in any file you can use it for link

Ex: in your  navHearder.php use like this:

```
<li class="active"><a href="<?=BASE_URL?>index.php">About</a></li>
```

suppose your file is in directory then:

```
<a href="<?=BASE_URL?>dir_name/file_name.php">link</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! May I know where should I apply the "define" line code?

Comment: In the common file which you are including in all files

Answer (score 0):

### Problem with `include`

The `include` statement relates file according to the location relative to the entry point. For example, if you have a file structure like this:

- /

  - /uploadTesting2

    - /login.php
  - /navHeader.php
  - /data.php

When you visits `/uploadTesting2/login.php` as the entry point, the location of `navHeader.php` and `data.php` should be `../navHeader.php` and `../data.php`. This is true even within the scripts included by `login.php`. So `navHeader.php` should only find `data.php` in as `../data.php`.

A usual way to solve this issue is to use `__DIR__` constant as a reference. This constant will always to be the script file's parent folder (not the entry file). If you echo `__DIR__` inside `navHeader.php`, it will be the system path of your root no matter what is including it.

Thus instead of this include statement:

```
include './data.php';
```

you may do this:

```
include __DIR__ . '/data.php';
```

### Problem with links

Links is also resolved relative to your current path. Thus

```
<a href="collectionPage.php?cat=abc">
```

in `/uploadTesting2/index.php` URL resolves to `/uploadTesting2/collectionPage.php?cat=abc`. Instead you should do

```
<a href="../collectionPage.php?cat=abc">
```